# How to set Authorization header in Rest API Basic Authentication

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven

Currently I am working in REST API in Java. My RestAPI is in separate maven project, And web application is in separate maven project. I have handled Basic Authentication in RestAPI. I want to set **Authorization in response header and also need to get it from HttpRequest in each request(Is this best practice?)**

Once I login into the application, login Username and password will forward to API, If once login credentials are valid, need to set Authorization header in Response. Each and every time I want to check the header whether the credentials are valid.

My Question is,

1. How to set Authorization Header, and where to set?
2. Either I want to set header in every response or only once?

My Web.xml(RestAPI)

```
<http realm="MY APP REALM">
    <csrf disabled="true" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

</http>
<beans:bean name="bcryptEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />
<beans:bean name="ser"
    class="com.test.api.config.SampleUserDetailsService" />
<beans:bean name="userService" class="com.test.api.service.impl.UserServiceImpl" />

<beans:bean name="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="com.test.api.config.MyAppBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint" />


<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="ser">
        <password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**REST API CONTROLLER**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class RestServiceController {

@Autowired
IUserService userService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Users>> listAllUsers() {
    List<Users> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    if (users.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Users>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);// You many decide to return
                                                                        // HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Users>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}

}
```

Help me to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyHandlerInterceptorAdapter extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
      response.setHeader("Authorization", "token");

       return true;
    }
```